# pyspark: Insert overwrite into a partitioned Table but the whole table is overwrite

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am new in Hive and spark, trying to overwrite a partitioned table accounting to its partition column, this is the code:

```
df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView(tempTable)
insertSql = "INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE {} PARTITION(dt) SELECT column1, column2, dt FROM {}".format(exportTable, tempTable)
spark.sql(insertSql)
```

the origin exportTable:

```
column1 column2 dt
x1      x2      20210914
x3      x4      20210914
x5      x6      20210914
y1      y2      20210915
y3      y4      20210915
```

tempTable:

```
column1 column2 dt
x7      x8      20210914
x9      x10     20210914
```

expected exportTable:

```
column1 column2 dt
x7      x8      20210914
x9      x10     20210914
y1      y2      20210915
y3      y4      20210915
```

but the exportTable like this, totally overwrite by the tempTable.:

```
column1 column2 dt
x7      x8      20210914
x9      x10     20210914
```

my spark version is 2.2 and I have to use this version...

why this sql cann't work? Is there any problems?

Comment: what does `spark.conf.get("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode")` show?

Comment: there is no this property in spark2.2, i think

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20236   Overwrite a partitioned data source table should only overwrite related partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hive table I would like to overwrite is created by using this:

```
df.write.saveAsTable()
```

this api will create a parquet format table, which will be fully overwrite when executing `INSERT OVERWRITE`, so first is to change the table format from parquet to ORC(Hive), then using `INSERT OVERWRITE` ; second is to use the following to create hive table every time:

```
df.write.format('hive').saveAsTable()
```